# C# Variable length string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Based on comboBox1 selection, I populate comboBox2.  The comboBox2 has a variable quantity of list items.  Currently I am doing this manually like this:

```
string[] str1 = { "item1", "item2" }
string[] str2 = { "item1", "item2", "item3" , "item4" }
```

etc.

```
if (cbox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
       cbox2.Items.AddRange(str1);
}
if (cbox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
       cbox2.Items.AddRange(str2);
}
```

etc.

Although this works, I have events for 4 drop downs and 13 possible choices for each.  This makes for a lot of if's.  I would prefer to do this with an array of strings so that I can get rid of all of the if's and just do the following for each SelectedIndexChanged:

```
cbox2.Items.AddRange(str[cbox1.SelectedIndex]);
```

but I am not sure if I can do this with the variable lengths of the strings.  I get errors when doing:

```
string[,] str = { { "Item1", "Item2"},{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"} };
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already discovered that you cannot use a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) in this situation, because your arrays have different lengths. However you could use a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) instead:

```
string[][] str =
{
    new string[] { "Item1", "Item2" },
    new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary and map your SelectedIndex values to string arrays (or even better, `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
IDictionary<int, string[]> values = new Dictionary<int, string[]>
                                 {
                                    {0, new[] {"item1", "item2"}},
                                    {1, new[] {"item3", "item4", "item5"}},
                                 };
...
string[] items = values[1];
```

Comment: I had not thought of this, I will at least try this solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a dictionary to accomplish your goal:

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> itemChoices = new Dictionary<int,string>()
{
    { 1, new [] { "Item1", "Item2" }},
    { 2, new [] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" }}
};
```

Then you can simply call:

```
cbox1.Items.AddRange(itemChoices[cbox1]);
cbox2.Items.AddRange(itemChoices[cbox2]);
```

Comment: and apparently @Strillo beat me to clicking post (I was originally going to use LINQ); though my implementation is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks also for your solution.